# Entity framework with Unity "The underlying provider failed on Open."

Tags: c#, entity, unity-container

I'm working on upgrading one of my companies projects to newer versions of MVC, Entity Framework and Unity.  Most of the work has been completed however, I do have this problem when loading data from the database. This does not happen on every request and most of the application functions normally. The problem occurs on API calls the application does when there are a couple of concurrent calls.

I've tried switching the LifeTimeManager of the Unity containers to different types with different results (none of them actually fixed the problem).

This is my DataContext class

```
    public class DataContext : IUnitOfWork, IRepositoryFactory
    {
        private const string CONSTRING = "CONSTRING";
        private static volatile DbContext dbContext = new DbContext(CONSTRING);

        private static volatile ConcurrentBag<object> repositories = new ConcurrentBag<object>();

        public DbContext DbContext => dbContext;

        public DataContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(null);
        }

        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            dbContext.Dispose();
        }

        public IRepository<T> CreateRepositoryFor<T>() where T : class, IEntity
        {

            var reposType = typeof(Repository<T>);

            var repos = (IRepository<T>)repositories.FirstOrDefault(r => r.GetType() == reposType);

            if (repos == null)
            {
                repos = new Repository<T>(dbContext.Set<T>());


                repositories.Add(repos);
            }

            return repos;
        }

    }
```

This is my UnityConfig

```
    public class UnityConfig
    {
        #region Unity Container
        private static readonly Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            RegisterTypes(container);
            return container;
        });

        /// <summary>
        /// Configured Unity Container.
        /// </summary>
        public static IUnityContainer Container => container.Value;
        #endregion

        public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            RegisterDependencies(container);

            System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolverAdapter(container));
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
        }

        private static void RegisterDependencies(IUnityContainer unityContainer)
        {
            RegisterDataContextAndUnitOfWork(unityContainer);
            RegisterRepositories(unityContainer);
        }

        private static void RegisterDataContextAndUnitOfWork(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, DataContext>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IRepositoryFactory, DataContext>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IChangeTracker, DataContext>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType(typeof (ICrudService<>), typeof (GenericCrudService<>));

        }

        private static void RegisterRepositories(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            // Haal MethodInfo op zodat we at runtime de static RegisterRepository<T> kunnen aanroepen
            var registerRepositoryMethodName = MemberNameHelper.GetActionName(() => RegisterRepository<IEntity>(container));
            var registerRepositoryMethodInfo = typeof(UnityConfig).GetMethod(registerRepositoryMethodName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

            // Registreer een repository voor iedere IEntity class in Domain project
            foreach (var entityType in typeof(IEntity).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(IEntity).IsAssignableFrom(t)))
            {
                var registerRepositoryMethod = registerRepositoryMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(entityType);
                registerRepositoryMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { container });
            }
        }

        private static void RegisterRepository<T>(IUnityContainer unityContainer) where T : class, IEntity
        {
            unityContainer.RegisterFactory<IRepository<T>>(
                factory => factory.Resolve<IRepositoryFactory>().CreateRepositoryFor<T>(),
                new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()
            );
        }
    }
```

The connectionstring is: `Data Source=LOCALHOST;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True`

The error message is: `The underlying provider failed on Open.`

Comment: What is your connection string?

Comment: What does this have to do with Unity3D, the game engine?  Please check your tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call `dbContext.Connection.Open();` method after initialize your `dbContext` variable. This will open connection for EF

Comment: I've added it to my DBContext class, it seems to work.  But I will test it further tomorrow at work.

Comment: After testing; this does seem to be the solution to my main problem.  It stopped all of my exceptions about the connection, but do still have some other relatable issues. So I'm back to fixing that.  On the matter of my question, thank you for your help!